# Pysentiment can't connect with the LM (Loughran and McDonald) dictionary i.e. ps.LM() error

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

https://github.com/hanzhichao2000/pysentiment is the code I am trying to work for me as I want to evaluate if a piece of text is positive or negative.

I really don't understand why it's not working and I would be very happy if someone could give any advice. (It may be relevant to know that I am running this on a school PC where I need it to work i.e. the path to python (2.7) is therefore not as simple as usual, thus I dowload folders instead of doing pip install or similar and add them to the Lib folder)

I post the entire error code bellow as I do not know what may be most relevant. Thank you!

```
import pysentiment as ps

lm = ps.LM()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-cd6a13354c8a>", line 1, in <module>
    lm = ps.LM()

  File "pysentiment\base.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.init_dict()

  File "pysentiment\lm.py", line 20, in init_dict
    terms = data['Word'][data[category] > 0]

  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\6F9A7389-FA64-4C13-A3B9-539B0D5EBBE5\8405BD12-8798-436E-AEE5-B79704BB086F\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1797, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\6F9A7389-FA64-4C13-A3B9-539B0D5EBBE5\8405BD12-8798-436E-AEE5-B79704BB086F\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1804, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\6F9A7389-FA64-4C13-A3B9-539B0D5EBBE5\8405BD12-8798-436E-AEE5-B79704BB086F\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1084, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)

  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\6F9A7389-FA64-4C13-A3B9-539B0D5EBBE5\8405BD12-8798-436E-AEE5-B79704BB086F\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2851, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\6F9A7389-FA64-4C13-A3B9-539B0D5EBBE5\8405BD12-8798-436E-AEE5-B79704BB086F\Root\VFS\AppVPackageDrive\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1572, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))

  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3824)

  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3704)

  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 686, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12280)

  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 694, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12231)

KeyError: 'Word'
```